# How to execute function when software ended with normal close (X) or un expected error thrown

Tags: c#, wpf, terminate-handler

I would like to execute a function when the running application terminated via normal close way (right top X) or un expected error happened and software terminated.

How can i do this at c# 4.5 WPF application

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `App.xaml.cs` -

- Override `OnStartUp` method and hook `UnhandledException` event of
  `Current AppDomain`, it will get called whenever application was
  about to close because of some unhandled exception.
- Override `OnExit` method for normal close of application.
- Create `CleanUp` method and call the method from above two methods.

  ```
  protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
  {
      base.OnStartup(e);
      AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new
         UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
  }

  private void CleanUp()
  {
      // Your CleanUp code goes here.
  }

  protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
  {
      CleanUp();
      base.OnExit(e);
  }

  void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender,
                                        UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
  {
      CleanUp();
  }
  ```

Comment: this is WPF application so it does not recognize OnStartup and OnExit

Comment: It does, you need to place this code in your `App.xaml.cs` file. Have you tried it?

Comment: but i am not able to access variables at main windows thread so this seems usless :(

Comment: Which variables you need to access?

Comment: i have public TextWriter and need to flush it when closing or un expected error handled.

Comment: please note that you asked the question "how to execute function when..". Both @RV1987 and I have showed you how you can execute a function (a method) when those conditions are met. The new problem you are facing is related to basic OOP and it implies general knowledge about encapsulation and addressability between various parts of your application. So it's not "useless", it's only midway of what you _actually_ wanted to ask...

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the `Exit` event of the app's `Application` subclass main instance
and the `UnhandledException` event of the current `AppDomain` instance like so:

```
public partial class App : Application {

    public App() {
        this.Exit += App_Exit;
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
    }

    void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) {
        MessageBox.Show("Exception " + e.ExceptionObject.GetType().Name);
    }

    void App_Exit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e) {
        MessageBox.Show("Bye bye");
    }   

}
```

Please note that given the following (simulated by clicking some buttons)
scenarios for unhandled exceptions:

[image]

which handle their respective click events like so:

```
    private void buttonThrowNice_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        throw new Exception("test");
    }

    private void buttonStackOverflow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        this.buttonStackOverflow_Click(sender, e);
    }

    private void buttonFailFast_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        Environment.FailFast("my fail fast");
    }

    private void buttonOutOfMemory_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        decimal[,,,,,] gargantuan = new decimal[int.MaxValue,int.MaxValue,int.MaxValue,int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue];
        Debug.WriteLine("Making sure the compiler doesn't optimize anything: " + gargantuan.ToString());
    }
```

The `UnhandledException` event of the `AppDomain` class only handles:

- *regular* exceptions
- the `OutOfMemoryException`

whereas the:

- *failfast*
- and the `StackOverflow` exception

are not caught.

Comment: thanks a lot for answer but it does not have this.Exit method

Comment: `this.Exit` is not a method, it's and event. "it" being the App class ? You are using WPF right ?